# AngularJS' "multidir" error when using ng-include and msSidenav in Angular Material

Tags: angular-material

My project is based on Angular Material framework (basically: Angular + web components in Material Design).

The problem I got into is that for some reason one directive ( **md-sidenav**) causes **multidir** error.

```
<md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="false" ng-controller="sideMenuController">
</md-sidenav>
```

I'm sure **md-sidenav** is the bad guy since I tried to replace it with another directive and got not issue at all. I'm also sure this directive is used nowhere else in the project, neither the controller associated to it is.

I also noticed **this error appeared after I switched to a nested layout** (i.e. ng-includes within the main view) but since I made several other changes to the project I can't be sure this is the actual reason.

I created a Plunkr to show the issue.
It actually doesn't run because I have no idea how to include ngRoute since a CDN is not available (feel free to edit the Plukr).

http://plnkr.co/edit/M52I7pn8D4fUaGAlOMtn

Comment: I dont see any side-nav in your code, here is the working plnker http://plnkr.co/edit/yuvtrPs3csAQZW7OF06O?p=preview

Comment: It's my mistake. For some reason I pasted the wrong plunkr. please check out my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two mistakes , you have not put the reference as text/javascript for **angualr-route** script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Embed the sidenav inside a div, since it is already having a directive for it,

```
<div ng-controller="sideMenuController">
<md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="false" >
</md-sidenav>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. it works!
can you please explain me what's the difference between placing the controller inline and embedded?
Since my controller is completely empty (i.e. does nothing) I don't get what's the problem